# What happened to my OP8 weapons?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was on my second Character, and had him at [OP8](http://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/864978109946686876/) very early into the first play through. I then completed True Vault Hunter Mode on [OP8](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Vault_Hunter_Upgrade_Pack_Two:_Digistruct_Peak_Challenge), I then went to play Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode on [OP8](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Vault_Hunter_Upgrade_Pack_Two:_Digistruct_Peak_Challenge) and I was back at LVL72 and could no longer play with my [OP8](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Vault_Hunter_Upgrade_Pack_Two:_Digistruct_Peak_Challenge) weapons.

**So does anyone know why this is happening? Is it a bug? Or is there something I should not have done?**

What is OP (in case you are confused)? OP8 is a short term for 'Over Powered LVL8' it is part of the new DLC, in which you receive LVL80 gear for your LVL72 character. More information [HERE](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Vault_Hunter_Upgrade_Pack_Two:_Digistruct_Peak_Challenge).

Comment: I have edited the question to the best of my capability but I am still unsure about what you did that caused you to lose your OP8 weapons

Comment: I dont think you read my question properly.

Comment: I still have my weapons but cant use them,because i went from op8 to 72 but i still got my gear.My question was why am i now level72 , when i was op8?

Comment: I meant what you just said

Comment: So, for clarification, upon completing TVHM you were OP8.  However, when starting UVHM, you were at lvl. 72?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Mind going into details on how you did that?  The [wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Vault_Hunter_Upgrade_Pack_Two%3a_Digistruct_Peak_Challenge#How_to_Overpower) says: *Once you reach level 72 and complete the Digistruct Peak arena **in UVHM**, you’ll unlock Overpower Level 1*

Comment: Easy just make a new character start a new story mode get someone with a op8 chararer to join your game and you can reach level 72 pretty quick  then go op area and get people to op you and Bam your op8 doing the first play through.nothing wrong with doing that.If you play solo it be how you were saying.That is what i did my first character it took me 3 months to get to op8.This way i did it in a hour.

Comment: I think it happened because you completed a different playthrough.