# How do i use my op8 weapons again?

Tags: borderlands-2

Basically, my friend is op8 and he got me op8 by going to distruct peak and doing all of that stuff you need to do there, then I went on my normal story mode so i could complete it (as i had only done the first few missions) and i was still op8 and everything. After completing it i went onto true vault hunter mode and it wont let me use my op8 guns. Ive looked everywhere on the internet for answers to this but cant find anything anywhere. My friends say i need to change the game mode to op8 but i dont know what theyre going on about because i cant find it anywhere. If you could help it would be appreciated.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162920/what-happened-to-my-op8-weapons duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

When you finish True Vault Hunter mode it unlocks Ultimate Vault Hunter mode. You must complete Ultimate Vault hunter mode to unlock Overpower Level 1, if you complete Overpower Level 1 it will unlock Overpower Level 2. You must complete Overpower Level 7 in story mode and load Overpower Level 8 to use Overpower Level 8 weapons and gear.